# Use multiple network devices with Internet on Windows 10 Pro for VMware

Tags: networking, vmware, routing, windows-10

**What I have**:
a Windows 10 Pro notebook with connected WiFi and connected ethernet, both NICs (separately with each his own different default gateway) providing a full Internet connection. I'm also using VMware Workstation.

**The outcome I'm looking for**:
use the WiFi internet connection for all my VMware machines (as default gateway) to access the internet, and the ethernet connection as default gateway for my host OS Windows.

*Under different circumstance I'd probably connect one network device directly to a VM and use it for routing, but given that the VMs are Linux and my wifi network device may not work that well on this I'd rather not go that way.*

- Is there a way provided by Windows to allow for inter-network-device routing on Windows 10 Pro? (host-OS -> ethernet, VMnet8-NAT-device -> WiFi)
- ..or is that a kind of featureset that'd require a server-edition Windows? (There would be additional network modules in Windows 10 Pro optional features.)

I don't mind using `netsh` or `route` to achieve that goal, I'm just a little lost as to how to approach this issue.

Comment: Are both NICs on the same subnet with the same gateway out?

Comment: Is this for VMware Workstation?

Comment: I added a clarification for your comments, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

VMware Workstation does not give you the option of which physical network adapter to use for NAT.  It does if you use a bridged network.

[image]

I am not sure if the following will work for NAT: Go into Windows `Network Connections` select your Physical Network adapter, right click and open `Properties`.  There you will be able to uncheck `VMware Bridge Protocol`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! While I distinctly remember that option existing a while back, it no longer does on Windows 10 and VMware Workstation 11.1.2, sorry.

Comment: @deucalion By "option" and "it" do you mean choosing the adapter for a bridged network?

Comment: My apologies, the "VMware Bridge Protocol" no longer is part of the list of items in a NIC's properties. I think that would have to do with the way VMware implements bridging in the current version.